# “403 – Forbudden: Access is denied.” but root CA installed correctly

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate, windows-server-2012, x509

I installed my root certificate to the “Local Machine\Trusted Root Certificates” store on my server(IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012).

When I try to access the site I get “403 – Forbudden: Access is denied.” error.

This is very weird. Once it allowed me to access the site and then block the site on the next try.

Server reports below failedRequest errors for all unsuccessful attempts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="https://<mysite>:443/"
               siteId="X"
               appPoolId="XXX"
               processId="6688"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0E17-0080000800DD}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
</failedRequest>
```

I am wondering if anyone has come across this issue or able to help me?

I have already tried workaround mentioned here but no luck - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2802568

Thanks a lot,

Comment: This issue is related to client authentication, not to server SSL. What authentication methods you use in IIS?

Comment: Thanks CryptoGuy. I'm using iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication